# Running GParted (with sudo) on Wayland

Tags: sudo, wayland

I want to use GParted on Ubuntu Artful (17.10) which is running Gnome on Wayland. When I start GParted I get the `gksu` prompt to enter my password but then nothing happens.

When I start GParted from the command line via `gksudo gparted` I see the possible problem:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

When I run GParted in the XOrg Gnome session everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to allow root to display the application on the desktop. To do that I had to enter this into the command line

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

Found the solution here [gparted-forum.surf4.info](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17446) and here [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/102936/graphical-applications-cant-be-run-as-root-in-wayland-eg-gedit-beesu-gparted-nautilus/)